# Double wrapped ItemView content with backbone.js and marionette.js

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

Here is an ItemView template called activatetwoitem

```
<!--  <tr>-->
<td><%= gatewayJson.serial %></td>
<td>In Inventory</td>
<td><%= gatewayJson.macaddress %></td>
<!-- </tr>-->
```

Here is the CompositeView template called activatetwo

```
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Gateway ID</th>
        <th>In Group</th>
        <th>MAC Address</th>
    </tr>

</thead>

<tbody></tbody></table>
```

Here is the ItemView

```
Step2View = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend
    template: activatetwoitem
    tagName: 'tr'
```

Here is the compositeView

```
Step2Views = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend
    itemView: Step2View
    template: activatetwo
    itemViewContainer: "tbody"
```

Now I am getting this...

```
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Gateway ID</th>
        <th>In Group</th>
        <th>MAC Address</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <!--  <tr>-->
        <tr>
            <td>AX1OD</td>
            <td>In Inventory</td>
            <td>secret mac address</td>
            <!-- </tr>-->
        </tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <!--  <tr>-->
        <tr>
            <td>12RUM</td>
            <td>In Inventory</td>
            <td>secret mac address</td>
            <!-- </tr>-->
        </tr>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Why am I getting that?  If I take out the tagName then the  somehow still shows up (with a div of course instead of the 2nd tr) any thoughts?

Comment: that's very odd... i use the same set up a lot. can you post a JSFiddle that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Do you do the commented out html as well?  Taking that out fixed mine.

Comment: hmm,no. can't say i've done that before... but it honestly never crossed my mind as a potential problem, when looking at your post. i'll have to try that and see what happens.

Comment: Do you use underscore or lodash for templates? I had a problem with comments in a old lodash release...

Comment: Using underscore.js templates.  I am also using this require.js plugin https://github.com/ZeeAgency/requirejs-tpl ... That shouldn't matter though I wouldn't think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't look at why, but when I took out the commented html from the template, the extra  wrapper went away.  Too bad, because I like the commented lines in the template to remind me about what is supposed to go there.